# How to translate a sentence about an experiment?

Tags: traducción

I want to say the following in sentence

> Your goal is to decided how related the two meanings of this word are
>   to one another. Another way to think of this would be, how similar, on
>   a scale of one to seven, in meaning are these two meanings to one
>   another.

This is what I have:

> Su objetivo es determinar el grado de relación entre las dos
>   definiciones. Otra manera de pensar de esto es, que vas a decidir en
>   una escala de uno a siete, si lo que las definiciones significan son
>   similar o no.

Could someone fix this or make it so that the meaning of what I'm trying to say gets across easier.  Does this at all seem unclear?

Comment: "Su objetivo es decidir cómo relacionado los dos significados de esta palabra son el uno al otro. Otra forma de pensar de esto sería, cómo es similar, en una escala de uno a siete, en sentido son estos dos significados entre sí" that's google's translation. Maybe it's just me but as a native Spanish speaker (although I've lost alot of fluency) but that doesn't seem right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La traducción puede ser:

> "Su objetivo es determinar el grado de relación entre las dos definiciones. Otra manera de pensar esto es "en una escala del uno a siete", si las definiciones tienen un significado similar o no."

Ya que la traducción no siempre se puede realizar literalmente, se requiere contextualizar el texto para obtener una mejor comprensión.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility:

> Su objetivo (or "El objetivo") es determinar el grado de relación entre las dos definiciones. Una manera de pensar **en** esto es que **va** a decidir, en una escala de uno a siete, si lo que las definiciones significan son similar**es** o no.

- use or preposition "**en**" instead of "de" for "think of this"
- If you say "**Su** objetivo" say "(usted) va a decidir". If you say "**Tu** objetivo" then use "(tú) **vas** a decidir". I would stick to the formal language for a form like this.
- "lo que las definiciones significan **son** similar**es**" concordance of number here. To improve it even further "si los significados de las definiciones son similares".

Comment: +1 por la traducción mas completa.

Comment: I added this answer as _community wiki_. I understand that technically this question is off-topic, but I withdrew my VTC. I may post on meta about this to discuss it further, but I feel that there should be room for these kind of questions, provided certain conditions. I understand that there could be plenty of "correct answers" when "optimizing" a text, so I started a CW post where other users may contribute with their own versions, variations or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to decided how related the two meanings of this word are to one another. Another way to think of this would be, how similar, on a scale of one to seven, in meaning are these two meanings to one another

Su objetivo es decidir que tan relacionados están los significados de esta palabra uno con otro.  Otra forma de pensar en esto seria,  que tan similares o parecidos en una escala de uno a siete,  son en significado, los significados uno comparado con el otro.